# KnockoutJS MVC Partial view selected information

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller, knockout.js, partial-views

I'm trying to implement a partial view to my HTML page where I expand the size of the QR Code that's on screen to make it easier for the user to see whenever they are to click the button showQRPanel.

HTMLPAGE:

```
<div data-bind="using: DetailsArray">
    <table style="padding: 9px; border: 1px solid;" data-bind="foreach: DetailsArray">
        <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
            <th>Patient</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>QR</th>
            <th>img</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: patient"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: mobnum"></td>
            <!--ko if: mobnum-->
            <td><img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" data-bind="attr: { 'src': '@Url.Action("QrGenerator", "Home")?mobnum_text=' + mobnum }" /></td>
            <td><button id="showQRPanel" data-bind="click: $root.ShowPanel">...</button></td>
            <!--/ko-->
        </tr>
    </table>

        <!--ko if: ShowPanel-->
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/_QRPanel.cshtml")
        <!--/ko-->

</div>
```

Partial View:

```
<div style="background-color: slategrey; width: 53%;" data-bind="with: $root.DetailsArray">

    <h2>Phone Number:</h2>
    <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" data-bind="attr: { 'src': '@Url.Action("QrGenerator", "Home")?mobnum_text=' + mobnum }" />

</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
    ShowPanel: ko.observable(false),

    DetailsArray: ko.observableArray([
        { patient: "niall", age: "13", mobnum: "0793983720"},
        { patient: "jacob", age: "13", mobnum: "07939837332"},
        { patient: "sam", age: "15", mobnum: ""},
    ])
};



ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think you need the `using` binding in your `div` at the top.  Please check the documentation for the using binding (https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html).

Second, the bindings in your partial view aren't quite right.  The `img` is trying to bind to `mobnum`, but you don't have a `mobnum` property on your viewmodel.  Rather, you have one one each of the items in your array, but you haven't told the binding how it knows which one to use.

Third, your click handler on your buttons call the `ShowPanel` method.  However, `ShowPanel` is an observable, so when you call it, all it does is return it's value, which is ignored by the click handler.

After removing the `using: DetailsArray` at the top of the HTML page, try this:

Viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = {
    SelectedMobNum: ko.observable(),

    ShowPanel: function(item) {
        viewModel.SelectedMobNum(this.mobnum);
    },
    ClosePartialView: function() {
      viewModel.SelectedMobNum(null);
    },

    DetailsArray: ko.observableArray([
        { patient: "niall", age: "13", mobnum: "0793983720"},
        { patient: "jacob", age: "13", mobnum: "07939837332"},
        { patient: "sam", age: "15", mobnum: ""},
    ])
};
```

Partial View (noticed I removed the `with` binding):

```
<div data-bind="visible: SelectedMobNum">

    <h2>Phone Number:</h2>
    <img data-bind="attr: { 'src': '@Url.Action("QrGenerator", "Home")?mobnum_text=' + SelectedMobNum() }" />
    <button data-bind="click: ClosePartialView">Close</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Great CodeThug, Thank you for your help this has helped me alot! There was something I had to change in which was the img tag within the partial view, the line "?mobnum_text=' + mobnum" had to be changed to "?mobnum_text=' + SelectedMobNum()".

Comment: I updated it with your fix.  If that takes care of it, can you mark this as the answer?